# In what ways did the Insular Indic languages morphologically diverge from Maharashthri Prakrit?

Tags: historical-linguistics, morphology, comparative-linguistics, indian-languages, indo-aryan

Maharashtri Prakrit is the antecedent southern zone language to all insular Indic languages. What are some characteristics, morphologically speaking, which differentiate these insular languages from their continental counterparts?

Comment: Is the descendance of Singhala from Marashtri Prakrit established now? My rather old knowledge is that Singhala is so mixed up that its regional descend from the Indian subcontinent cannot be determined.

Answer (score -1):

Sinhala has borrowed lot of words and terms from Tamil,which is a member of Dravidian language division.That peculiarity you observed is mainly due to the above reason.
But Sinhala still maintains a rich vocabulary full of Sanskrit and Magadhi.

Comment: The question asks about morphological features: are they the same, or are they different?